# How to write special characters in URL in JAVA code

Tags: java, urlencode

I'm trying to write a code for GET Request in Java. But the URL contains special characters. How to handle those special characters so it is able to hit the API with the correct request target?
The URL which I am using is similar to this: [https://xyz.tech.environment/v1/payments?page[last]&filter[reference]=1234](https://xyz.tech.environment/v1/payments?page%5Blast%5D&filter%5Breference%5D=1234). Do I need to encode page[last]&filter[reference]? If so, how to?

Comment: You need to use `URLEncoder` on the arguments only, separately for each one. Not the URL itself.

Comment: As suggested by @user207421, you can use URLEncoder. This solution may help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10786112/5685911